# php_decode not working as intended?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, twitter-oauth

I've been stuck on this problem for a while and I am not able to figure this out. So from a MySql backend DB some JSON (text form) is pulled and then that JSON is decoded to form an associative array.

Now after that I print the textual JSON out and the associative array. Randomly some of them have an associative array and some dont print anything. Thats the **problem**. All of the JSON are **VALID**. I double checked them using JSON Lint. Also for the JSON that could not be printed out as an associative array, I tried doing that separately in online php executor and it worked there. It did print the associative array there.

Here is some stuff:

Part of my code:

```
    // $twitterUsers =  List of 10 users used to query the DB.
    foreach($twitterUsers as $user){

            // Select a random number between 1 and 200
            $rand = mt_rand(1, 200);

            $query = "SELECT TwitterResp FROM Tweets WHERE Number = ".(string)$rand." AND TwitterHandle = \"".$user."\";";
            $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);

            $row = $res->fetch_array();

            $twitterResp = $row[0];
            echo $twitterResp;
            echo "<br><br><br>";
            $twitterRespJson = json_decode($twitterResp, true);
            print_r($twitterRespJson);

            echo "<br><br> ------------------------------------- <br><br>";


            while(count($res->fetch_array()) == 0){

                // Select a random number between 1 and 200
                $rand = mt_rand(1, 200);

                $query = "SELECT TwitterResp FROM Tweets WHERE Number = ".(string)$rand." AND TwitterHandle = \"".$user."\";";
                $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            }
}
```

The printed out result is huge. Sorry for the inconvenience but just wanted to show that it does not print the associative arrays for some. The result is here:
http://pasted.co/4d4447a8
I wanna know why...

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is possibly due to 'special' characters in the $twitterResp?

Comment: No that is not it. 
I tried this:
`$twitterRespJson = json_decode(utf8_encode($twitterResp), true);`

I did not work.

Comment: maybe it's the single quotes, try:
     json_decode(addslashes($twitterResp));

also, add json_last_error() to find out the last JSON error.

Comment: Nope. That didn't work and also by doing that all of the $twitterResp did not print the associative array.

Comment: add json_last_error() to find out the last JSON error.